# Eclipse - how to extend HTML editor to add custom tags?

Tags: html, eclipse, tags

I write an application and inside of HTML code I have custom tags (of course these tags are parsed on server side and end user gets them as valid HTML code). Example of custom tag usage:

```
<html>
<body>
...
    <Gallery type="grid" title="My Gallery" />
...
</body>
</html>
```

1.) How can I have eclipse recognize my custom tags inside of HTML code and add syntax highlighting to them?
2.) How can I add auto-suggestions to my custom tags? For example if I type "<Gallery " press "Ctrl+Space" - in the list of available attributes it shows me "type" and "title" and if I type "<Gallery type=" press "Ctrl+Space" I would see list of available values only for tag "Gallery" and its attribute "type".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, there is no easy way: you have to roll your own parser for this, and then add both your extra elements and the base grammar (HTML) to it.

If you have your parser, you could use it to do syntax highlighting (strictly speaking, for that simple lexing is enough); and a good parser can support content assist (auto-suggestions in your terminology).

Caveats:

- Creating a parser for HTML is not an easy task. Maybe by aiming at a more often used subset is feasible.
- If a parser exists, the editor parts are still hard to get well.

Some help on the other hand: you could use some text editor generators to ease your work:

- Eclipse IMP http://www.eclipse.org/imp/ can in theory handle any type of parser, but currently it is most optimized for LPG. The documentation is scarce, but the developers are helpful in the forums.
- Xtext http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/ got quite a hype for creating text editors for DSLs. The generated editors are quite nice out of the box, but is not the best solution for large files. Has a really helpful developer community.
- EMFText http://www.emftext.org/index.php/EMFText is a lesser known entity - I don't know it in details, but I guess, it is similar to Xtext.

Answer (score 5):

Not really what you want, but maybe it helps you:

1. You can try the [Aptana Plug-in](http://aptana.org/products/studio3/download) for Eclipse. It allows to write your own regular expression for HTML validation, so a custom tag would be ignored by the validator.
   E.g.:

   .*gallery.*
2. Eclipse allows you to add simple auto-suggestions via **Templates**. On
   Eclipse 3.7.1 (Indigo) + PHP Dev Tools (PDT) 3.0.0: *Window > Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Editor > Templates*

Comment: Aptana Plug-in finally found a better html editor for eclipse. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

I know its been a long time since this Q was asked,
but I hope this might help others like myself that reach this in search of a solution.

So, When using Eclipse (Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) - and possibly earlier - I did not check).

Go to `Window` - `Prefrences`
Then in the dialog that opens go to `Web` - `HTML Files` - `Editor` - `Validation`.
On the right side:

1. under `Ignore specified element names in validation` and enter the list of custom elements you use. (e.g. `Gallery,tab,tabset,my-element-directives-*`)
2. you might also like to go under `Ignore specified attribute names in validation` do the same for your custom attributes.(e.g.  `ng-*,my-attr-directives-*`)

Two things to note:

1. After letting eclipse do a full validation you must also close the file and reopen it to have the warnings removed from the source code.
2. Using this method would ignore those attributes under any element. I don't think there is a simple way to tell it to ignore `some-attribute` only if its a child of `some-element`.

Answer (score 0):

I find templates are an ok alternative but let's see if we can encourage a more robust solution; please take a moment and vote for this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422584

Answer (score 0):

You need to **add a new HTML template**.To add a new template, complete the following steps:

1) From the Window menu, select Preferences.

2) In the Preferences page, select Web and XML > HTML Files > HTML Templates.

3) Click New.

4) Enter the new template name and a brief description of the template.

5) Using the Context drop-down list, specify the context in which the template is available.

6) In the Pattern field, enter the appropriate tags, attributes, or attribute values (the content of the template) to be inserted by content assist.

7) If you want to insert a variable, click the Variable button and select the variable to be inserted. For example, the word_selection variable indicates the word that is selected at the beginning of template insertion, and the cursor variable determines where the cursor will be after the template is inserted in the HTML document.

8) Click OK to save the new template.

You can edit, remove, import, or export a template by using the same Preferences page.

Reference : http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.sse.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftsrcedt024.html